# Asynchronous methods aren't always executed on Windows Phone 8 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, async-await

I'm developing an app that needs to run on one Windows Phone 8 device. The app needs to connect to several URLs and log the results of each connection attempt: the size of the response and the time the entire request-response takes. It mostly works, but I cannot get the async methods to play nice: not all attempts are logged. Usually the last test is not logged, which to me looks as if the relevant method doesn't get called.

Here's the relevant code from my MainViewModel:

```
private readonly BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker;

public MainViewModel()
{
    backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker { WorkerReportsProgress = true, WorkerSupportsCancellation = false };
    backgroundWorker.DoWork += BackgroundWorkerDoWork;
    backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += BackgroundWorkerProgressChanged;
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += BackgroundWorkerRunCompleted;
}

private void BackgroundWorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs args)
{
    var worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    if (worker == null) return;

    var testItems = new TestItemListCreator().Execute(NetworkType);
    var total = testItems.Count;

    var count = 0;
    foreach (var testItem in testItems)
    {
        count++;
        // because otherwise the logging fails
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)); 
        new TestExecutor().RunTest(testItem);
        worker.ReportProgress((count * 100) / total);
    }
}

private void BackgroundWorkerProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs args)
{
    ProgressPercent = args.ProgressPercentage;
}

private void BackgroundWorkerRunCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Error == null)
    {
        Message = "Done!";
    }
    else
    {
        Message = "Error: " + args.Error.Message;
    }
}

private void ExecuteRunTests()
{
    Message = "Please wait...";
    ProgressPercent = 0;

    if (backgroundWorker.IsBusy) return;

    CanExecuteRunTests = false;
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

This is the TestExecutor:

```
public class TestExecutor
{
    private readonly OAuthGetRequestExecutor oAuthGetRequestExecutor;

    public TestExecutor()
    {
        oAuthGetRequestExecutor = new OAuthGetRequestExecutor();
    }

    public void RunTest(TestItem testItem)
    {
        oAuthGetRequestExecutor.PerformGetRequest(testItem, RequestFinished);
    }

    private void RequestFinished(object sender, OAuthEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (eventArgs.IsError)
        {
            ErrorLogger.Log(eventArgs.ErrorMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            TestLogger.Log(eventArgs.TestItem);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the TestLogger:

```
internal class TestLogger
{
    private const string Separator = ";";

    public static async void Log(TestItem testItem)
    {
        await CsvFileAssistant.WriteToFile(string.Join(Separator, GetLine(testItem)) + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<object> GetLine(TestItem testItem)
    {
        return new List<object>
        {
            testItem.DateTime,
            testItem.NetworkCategory,
            testItem.NetworkType,
            testItem.TestName,
            testItem.TestResult.Sent,
            testItem.TestResult.Received,
            testItem.TestResult.Time
        };
    }
}
```

This is the CsvFileAssistant:

```
internal class CsvFileAssistant
{
    private static readonly StorageFolder DefaultFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    private const string FolderName = "Data";
    private const string FileName = "Tests.csv";

    public static async Task WriteToFile(string text)
    {
        var dataFolder = await DefaultFolder.CreateFolderAsync(FolderName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        var file = await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync(FileName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);

        using (var s = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            var fileBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text.ToCharArray());
            s.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.End);
            s.Write(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are probably comming from Java: if you find you have written classes that you call this way: `new ClassName().Method(x);` you have a conceptual error. You obviously do not care about an instance of said class at all, so make it a static class.

Comment: Why are you using BackgroundWorker when you have Tasks? BackgroundWorker is all-but-obsolete. You can address the same scenarios with Task.Run and a Progress<T> instance. In this case, BackgroundWorker only obscures what is going on

Comment: The code is too convoluted when all you should really need is a `var content=await myHttpClient.GetStringAsync(someUrl);myProgress.Report(count++) ;await CsvFileAssistant.WriteToFile(content);` inside a loop

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos If only it were that simple. OAuthGetRequestExecutor creates an OAuth request; I'm using code that was developed for another project to construct it.

Comment: @BCdotNET that occurs only inside the TestExecutor. The rest of the code can be simplified drastically. In fact, you can use TaskCompletionSource to convert the TestExecutor to a Task-based method. It *can* be made that simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've rewritten part of my project to avoid the EventHandler and to remove the BackgroundWorker.

Here's the MainViewModel:

```
private readonly IProgress<int> progress;

public MainViewModel()
{
    progress = new Progress<int>(value =>
    {
        ProgressPercent = value;
    });
}

private async void ExecuteRunTests()
{
    ProgressPercent = 0;

    var testItems = new TestItemListCreator().Execute(NetworkType);
    var total = testItems.Count;

    var count = 0;
    foreach (var testItem in testItems)
    {
        count++;

        var result = await new OAuthGetRequestExecutor().PerformGetRequest(testItem);
        await ResultLogger.Log(result);

        var percent = (count * 100) / total;
        progress.Report(percent);
    }
}
```

`ResultLogger` checks whether the `IsError` property of the `OAuthResult` is true and uses that to decide to call either the `ErrorLogger` or the `TestLogger`. No `async void` anywhere, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I think you violated Rule 1 when using async/await: Avoid async void. There is no way to tell whether they have been executed.

http://haacked.com/archive/2014/11/11/async-void-methods/

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
TestLogger.Log(eventArgs.TestItem);
```

Isn't being awaited because you're executing this from a synchronous method. Once you dont use `await`, you're simply using a "fire and forget" mechanism, which makes no guarantee that your method completes gracefully.

You're mixing the Event based Asynchronous Pattern with the new Task Asynchronous Pattern. I'd suggest you either use one or the other, but not together.

You shouldn't use `async void` except for event handlers, which is your case:

```
private async void RequestFinished(object sender, OAuthEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (eventArgs.IsError)
    {
        ErrorLogger.Log(eventArgs.ErrorMessage);
    }
    else
    {
        await TestLogger.Log(eventArgs.TestItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good tip to await calls and always check for Errors because if your async method fail App will not always break.

Comment: I already suspected that this was (part of) the issue. But how can I solve this? This EventHandler logic is part of the class that handles the OAuth request and I don't immediately see an easy way to rewrite it.

Comment: You can make OAuth expose an `async` method to be awaited, instead of a synchronous one.